# Python Slicing 'bob' in s

Tags: python, slice

```
    s = 'gfdhbobobyui'
    bob = 0
    for x in range(len(s)):
         if x == 'bob':
             bob += 1
    print('Number of times bob occurs is: ' + str(bob))
```

Attempting to write a code that will count the amount of times 'bob' appears in s, but for some reason this always outputs 0 for number of 'bob'.

Comment: Ahh why noone uses regex? `len(re.findall("(?=bob)", "gfdhbobobyui"))`

Comment: @Vik2015 I don't know why, but i studied regex for a few pages and i found out that i hate it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, try this, handcrafted :)

```
for i, _ in enumerate(s): #i here is the index, equal to "i in range(len(s))"
    if s[i:i+3] == 'bob': #Check the current char + the next three chars.
        bob += 1
print('Number of times bob occurs is: ' + str(bob))
```

**Demo**

```
>>> s = 'gfdhbobobyui'
>>> bob = 0
>>> for i, v in enumerate(s): #i here is the index, equal to "i range(len(s))"
    if s[i:i+3] == 'bob': #Check the current char + the next two chars.
        bob += 1


>>> bob
2
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, what is enumerate?

Comment: It returns a tuple of the index and the value. So i'm catching it with two variables, `v` is for the current value, and `i` is for the current index.

Comment: For details, see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) :)

Comment: I'll check that out appreciate it!

Comment: I'd suggest you to write `for i, _ in enumerate(s)` since you don't use `v`. Also, `enumerate` might be slightly slower than using `range(len(s))` and you also do 2 extra unnecessary iterations.

Answer (score 3):

`x` is a number, it can't be equal to `'bob'`. That's why it always output 0.

You should use `x` in order to get a substring of `s`:

```
bob = 0
for x in range(len(s) - 2):
    if s[x:x+3] == 'bob':
        bob += 1
```

You can also use `enumerate`.

Comment: OK thank you that makes since!

Answer (score 2):

```
s = 'gfdhbobobyui'
bob = 0
for x in range(len(s)):
     if s[x:x+3] == 'bob':  # From x to three 3 characters ahead.
         bob += 1
print('Number of times bob occurs is: ' + str(bob))
```

Working [example](http://ideone.com/sQVAcc).

But the best way is this, however it does not work with overlapping strings:

```
s.ount('bob')
```

Comment: actually, since you're only comparing the string, `len(s)` is sufficient.

Comment: Also, `str.count()` doesn't work with overlapping occurences :)

Comment: @aIKid You'll gen an index error.

Comment: Nope. I didn't. See my example, i copy pasted it.

Comment: @aIKid Well thats strange, it seems that slicing out of bounds raises no exception.

Comment: Yep. I'm curious of that too actually HAHAHA. But it just works.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Yep, there is no index error. However, why stopping at `len(s)-1` ?

Comment: @Maxime since if you're on the -1th index, it's impossible to have a three character word, isn't it? =)

Comment: @alKid exactly. So you can stop even earlier ;). That's what I'm saying.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac You have updated your answer but forgot to change the code on Ideone which was incorrect (didn't work with gfdhbobob because of the `-3` instead of `-2`).